# Does Oracle's ADO.NET data provider report wrong data types for NUMBER(x,y) and FLOAT or REAL?

Tags: oracle, ado.net, sqldatatypes

I suspect that Oracle's data provider for ADO.NET reports wrong data types for columns whose type is `NUMBER(x,y)`, `FLOAT` or `REAL`.

The following simple program creates a table with these data types and then prints the data types as reported by the data provider. When executed, it prints:

```
NUM: Double - System.Double - Double
FLT: Decimal - System.Decimal - Decimal
REL: Decimal - System.Decimal - Decimal
```

However, I feel, it should be the other way round and get a `DECIMAL` type for `FLT` and `REL` and a `Double` tyep for `NUM`.

Can someone confirm my suspicion?

```
using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

class Prg {

   static void Main() {

      OracleConnection ora = new OracleConnection($"user Id=rene;password=rene;data source=ORA18");
      ora.Open();

      OracleCommand stmt = ora.CreateCommand();
      stmt.CommandText = "begin execute immediate 'drop table DataTypeTest'; exception when others then null; end;";
      stmt.ExecuteNonQuery();

      stmt.CommandText = "create table DataTypeTest (num number(10,3), flt float, rel real)";
      stmt.ExecuteNonQuery();

      stmt.CommandText = "select * from DataTypeTest";
      OracleDataReader res = stmt.ExecuteReader(); 


      for (int fld=0; fld<res.FieldCount; fld++) {
         Console.WriteLine($"{res.GetName(fld)}: {res.GetDataTypeName(fld)} - {res.GetFieldType(fld)} - {Type.GetTypeCode(res.GetFieldType(fld))}");
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle Datatypes Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr06.htm#CHDJJEEA):

> `FLOAT [(p)]`
>
> A subtype of the `NUMBER` datatype having precision p. A `FLOAT` value is represented internally as `NUMBER`. The precision `p` can range from 1 to 126 binary digits. A `FLOAT` value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

And further down that documentation page:

> ANSI SQL Datatype: `REAL` (Note d)
>
> Oracle Datatype: `FLOAT(63)`
>
> Notes 1d: The `REAL` datatype is a floating-point number with a binary precision of 63, or 18 decimal.

So `REAL` is a sub-type of `FLOAT` which, in turn, is a sub-type of `NUMBER` and that `NUMBER` should allow the greatest precision and `REAL` the least precision of these data types.

> I suspect that Oracle's data provider for ADO.NET reports wrong data types for columns whose type is `NUMBER(x,y)`, `FLOAT` or `REAL`.

Looking at:

[ODBC Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/odbc-data-type-mappings):

> ```
> ODBC type     .NET Framework type
> -----------   -------------------
> SQL_REAL      Single
> SQL_NUMERIC   Decimal
> SQL_DOUBLE    Double
> ```

*(`SQL_FLOAT` was not listed in the table and may default to `SQL_NUMERIC`'s mapping since one is a sub-type of the other.)*

It does appear that your test data does not match with these mappings.

However:

- Since both `REAL` and `FLOAT` are sub-types of `NUMERIC` in the Oracle database then if they are being reported as their `NUMERIC` super-type rather than their specific sub-type then the mapping to `Decimal` does match the type mapping.
- Your `NUM` column is of type `NUMBER(10,3)` so can have at most 7 whole digits and 3 decimal places and it may be that the data provider has determined that this can be accurately stored in a `Double` data type and that a `Decimal` data type is overkill. You can see if a different data type is returned using `NUMBER` (without precision or scale) or `NUMBER(38,3)`.